# Make fly out current navigation background transparent

Tags: 2013, css, current-navigation

I want to make background of current navigation flyout transparent.
You can see on the image bellow what element I want to make invisible (white frame).
[image]

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally resolved this problem after help of colleague.
I called *ul* element of *dynamic* class from *sideNavBox* id.

```
 #sideNavBox ul.dynamic {
    background-color:transparent;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
 }
```